# Combine two performance tables

Tags: r, merge, performanceanalytics

I am looking for a practicable solution to the following problem:
I would like to combine two performance tables generated with the function `table.CalendarReturns` from the package `PerformanceAnalytics`.

One table contains the performance figures of the portfolio and could look like this:

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Jan = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Feb = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Mrz = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Apr = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Mai = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Jun = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Jul = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Aug = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Sep = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Okt = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Nov = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                  Dez = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10)

df$Return <- rowSums(df)
rownames(df) <- c(2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017)
```

For simplicity's sake, the return is shown as a total.

Benchmark figures could be:

```
set.seed(2)
df_bm <- data.frame(Jan = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Feb = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Mrz = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Apr = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Mai = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Jun = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Jul = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Aug = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Sep = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Okt = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Nov = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10,
                 Dez = sample(-60:140, 6, replace = T)/10)

df_bm$Return <- rowSums(df)
rownames(df_bm) <- c("2012 BM", "2013 BM", "2014 BM" ,"2015 BM" , "2016 BM" , "2017 BM")
```

My goal is to merge both tables so that the benchmark values for the respective months are inserted.

The result should look like this (for the years 2012 to 2013 Jan to March and so on...):

```
            Jan  Feb  Mrz
2012       -0.7 12.9  7.8
2012 BM    -2.3 -3.5 -9.2
2013        1.4  7.2  1.7
2013 BM     8.1 10.7 -2.3
```

Any ideas on that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: perhaps:`rbind(df, df_bm)[order(rownames(rbind(df, df_bm))),]`

Comment: Hi @missuse, it works perfect. Looks so simple but I didn't get it...Thx.